# How to get Call Events from Call.Callback and InCallService TelecomManager?

Tags: android

i'm working in an Android aplication and i would like to handle some telephony call events.

I don't like to replace current UI for making a call, just to handle events on call progress. i already use PhoneStateListener but there are only 3 states (**CALL_STATE_IDLE**, **CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK**, **CALL_STATE_RINGING**).

I would like to have access to [Call.Details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.Details) like [DisconnectCause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/DisconnectCause)

I don't now how to bind InCallService from my Activity. Here is some code to understand what i want to do.

MyService Class

```
public class MyService extends InCallService {


public static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    Log.d(TAG, "On Start");

    return START_STICKY;
}




@Override
public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
    super.onCallAdded(call);


    call.registerCallback(new CallbackTelecomHelper(this));

    Log.d(TAG, "onCallAdded");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCallAdded details" + call.getDetails());
}


@Override
public void onCallRemoved(Call call) {
    super.onCallRemoved(call);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCallRemoved");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCallRemoved details" + call.getDetails());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionEvent(Call call, String event, Bundle extras) {
    super.onConnectionEvent(call, event, extras);

    Log.d(TAG, "getDisconnect code: " + call.getDetails().getDisconnectCause().getCode());
    Log.d(TAG, "getDisconnect reason: " + call.getDetails().getDisconnectCause().getReason());
    Log.d(TAG, "getDisconnect description: " + call.getDetails().getDisconnectCause().getDescription());
    Log.d(TAG, "event : " + event);

}
```

CallbackTelecomHelper - helper class for **Call.Callback**

```
public class CallbackTelecomHelper extends Call.Callback {

String TAG = "CallbackTelecomHelper_TAG";

private Context context;

public CallbackTelecomHelper(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onStateChanged(Call call, int state) {
    super.onStateChanged(call, state);

    Log.i(TAG, "onStateChanged");
}

@Override
public void onDetailsChanged(Call call, Call.Details details) {
    super.onDetailsChanged(call, details);


    Log.i(TAG, "onDetailsChanged");
}

@Override
public void onCallDestroyed(Call call) {
    super.onCallDestroyed(call);

    Log.i(TAG, "onCallDestroyed");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionEvent(Call call, String event, Bundle extras) {
    super.onConnectionEvent(call, event, extras);


    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionEvent");
}

@Override
public void onRttRequest(Call call, int id) {
    super.onRttRequest(call, id);


    Log.i(TAG, "onRttRequest");
}
```

From My activity i start service :

```
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE);
telecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage();
Intent intentConnection =  new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(intentConnection);
```

Manifest settings :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.ScenarioMapActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

 <service android:name=".services.Connection.MyService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE">
        <meta-data android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Any idea how i can get access in this informations? 
Sorry for my english!

Comment: is this code working ? and what you want is to show the values to activity ?

Comment: i just want ot handle call events. 
When a call start and the reason when i call end (end normal from user, no signal, user never answered, user reject incoming call ).

I this code i can't get access to InCallService.

Comment: TelecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage() try to call this function in your MainActivity before executing service

Comment: i already did that

Answer (score 4):

The InCallService API is what Dialer/Phone apps use to implement an incall UI for ongoing phone calls.  There's not currently a way to get the system to bind to an InCallService implementation unless the user has chosen it as the default dialer.

Comment: do you know if this is still the case 3 years later ?

Comment: @j2emanue, the InCallService API is available to both the default Dialer, and starting in Android S it will be available to a watch companion app paired via the CompanionDeviceManager API.